# Inconsistency with beforeUnload across different browsers

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, onbeforeunload

I'm attempting to run a function (that sends some fetch calls to an API) inside of a "beforeunload" event handler and the results are mixed. With Chrome it successfully runs my function if the user reloads the page or clicks a link for a different webpage, but it doesn't work if they close the tab. In Firefox the function only runs if they close the tab, but not in any other scenario. When I debug the beforeunload handler in the browser I can see the event handler clearly is triggered but the function inside doesn't always run. I suspect the function I'm trying to feed being async is part of the issue but I don't know why the results would be so inconsistent?

This is how I'm currently writing the event handler

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', async function(evt){
       await exitChat();
    });
```

I've also tried not using async/await. Let me know if seeing the exitChat() function code would help or anything else.

Edit: After a bit more debugging I can confirm that the issue, with Chrome at least, is that when the window is closed it can't make it through the entire exitChat() function in time before the page closes. So is there a way to force a delay in the unloading process?

Comment: In a word: privacy. See [MDN's article on the event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event). Too many spammers were using it to stop people from leaving their sites, so browsers took different tacks in making users happy.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Is there another way you would recommend to fire off a function before a page is unloaded? Thank you.

Comment: @Cole36 since this is a chat-related action, it is probably better (and safer) to handle it on the server-side. For example, if you are handling the chat based on websockets, you can run this action when the socket connection breaks.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis thank you I am using sockets. How can I determine if the connection is broken? Sorry very new with using sockets

Comment: @Cole36 You can use an event such as disconnect on the server: socket.on('disconnect', handler ). Depending on the library, e.g. socket.io, search for the appropriate event/handler in the documentation or google for 'detect client disconnect socket.io'

Comment: IMHO I suggest reading https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/page-lifecycle-api and maybe you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon